# push data to multidimensional mongodb document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hi I have multi dimensional mongoDB document now I want to push new records to the **locations** filed with same objects time , lat , lng

here is my database record

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5979b1a81c4547652583397e"),
    "shenase" : "002",
    "name" : "??? ?????",
    "vehicle" : "?????",
    "locations" : {
        "time" : "2017-07-27 13:55:30",
        "latiude" : 35.7429305,
        "langtiude" : 51.5001943
    }
}
```

I want to know how can I do that with node js

Comment: `"locations"` needs to be an "array" in order to store multiple objects. It presently is not. You also should not be using named keys such as `"latitude"` and `"langitude"` ( which is actually "longitude" ), as there is a specific [GeoJSON format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/) you "should" be following. And even so, it's not best to put location data into an array if you intend Geospatial queries on it. It's possible, but not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your database schema is not correct. Locations must be an array and not an object. So the record must be

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5979b1a81c4547652583397e"),
  "shenase" : "002",
  "name" : "??? ?????",
  "vehicle" : "?????",
  "locations" : [
    "time" : "2017-07-27 13:55:30",
    "latiude" : 35.7429305,
    "langtiude" : 51.5001943
  ]
}
```

Now to push the new record onto array you can simply write

```
var data = {
    "time":"2017-07-29 13:55:30",
    "latitude": 18.0667,
    "longitude": 45.99890
};

YourModel.update(
   { _id: toBeUpdated._id }, 
   { $push: { location: data } },
   function(err,data){
       console.log(err,data);
   }
);
```